# Reading from stdin in Python 2.7.6. Sys.stdout.flush() and python -u doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout, stdin, eof

It seems like many people have been struggling with getting buffers and stdin and stout working across many flavors of Python. I'm writing a script in Python 2.7.6 to read from stdin, do a regex match, and print a list of matching strings.

```python
import re, sys

barcodes=["The barcodes are:"]
curr=barcodes[0]

#iterate through stdin
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
        #do regex match in line
        match = re.search('(?<=\:)[GATC]{6}', line.rstrip()).group(0)
        matched = 0
        #see if match has been seen before
        if (match == curr):
                matched = 1
                print "matched curr"
        else:
                for a , val in enumerate(barcodes):
                        if (match == val):
                                print str(a) + " : " + val + " barcodes[a] " + str(barcodes[a])
                                curr = barcodes[a]
                                print curr
                                matched = 1
                                print "matched iteration"
        #if match hasn't been seen before
        if (matched == 0):
                sys.stdout.write("NEW match")
                sys.stdout.flush()
                barcodes.append(match)

#print report of barcodes
for i in barcodes:
        print i
```

Like many before me have found, this waits until it reads an EOF block from stdin to print anything and I can't seem to find any documentation on how to have the process run/print as it reads from stdin.

To be clear, this happens regardless of whether or not I call Python with the -u flag.

Thank you for any guidance you can give me.

Comment: `.readlines()` will read the entire file (or stdin) in one go... You'll need to use `.read()` and find the newlines yourself.

Comment: Forgive me, but I've read through the documentation for file objects and it's unclear to me how I would use newlines to iterate through the string the sys.stdin.read() would return. Should I try to read from stdin using a set number of bytes, then parse the string into a list, and then iterate through each of those lists until I've read the whole file?

Comment: @DanBurkhardt: have you tried simply `for line in sys.stdin:`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I hadn't but that does work. Thank you! I think I was getting confused about sys.stdin being a file object so I hadn't been looking for methods of file objects.

Comment: @DanBurkhardt: you're welcome.  I added it as an answer since it seems to have worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples that read sys.stdin a line at a time. They do *not* require the use of the python `-u` option.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys

def main():
    count = 1
    while True:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        if line == '':
            break   #EOF encountered

        print "%3d: [%s]" % (count, line[:-1])
        count += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you are using Linux / Unix, this version is better because it gives you line editing.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import readline

def main():
    count = 1
    while True:
        try:
            line = raw_input()
            print "%3d: [%s]" % (count, line)
            count += 1
        except EOFError:
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for these. I had seen similar solutions earlier, but it just seemed crazy to me to need to use a while True loop. I was hoping there would be a way to avoid it, but in my final code, I ended up using your try : except blocks.

Comment: I guess it's because `stdin` is special. You _could_ use `for line in sys.stdin:` but then you'd need to send an EOF at the end of every line (or so), which is a bit annoying. :)

Answer (score 1):

`sys.stdin` is just a `file` object so if you use `readlines()` then reading would continue until all lines are read. This would happen only when you hit Ctrl+D (in Linux). Try reading line by line instead, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,re


while True:

     line = sys.stdin.readline()
     m = re.search("end", line)
     if m:  
        break
     else:
        print "I read:" + line
```

Comment: So does the end of stdin have a literal "end" at the EOF? I didn't expect the re.search for that string to work.

Comment: "end" is just my example. You should write your code to detect end of stdin. You can indicate end of stdin based on your requirement, say some input string or CTRL+D was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply this:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
     # process line
```

Since `sys.stdin` is a file-like object, iterating over it generates lines one at a time as they become available.